# optimizing frequency in a list of list, by each item's two first value

Tags: python, list, duplicates, frequency

I'm totally new to programming ( less than 2 months - self-taught ) and I'm working on a project which it needs the frequency of a list of list by the first two indexes at each inner list.

here is my list :

> x = [['block', 3], ['street', 2], ['lamp',1], ['street', 2],
>   ['industrial', 3], ['park', 2], ['park', 3], ['industrial', 3],
>   ['block', 3], ['street', 2], ['lamp',1], ['street', 2], ['industrial',
>   3], ['park', 2]]

so the first value at each inner list is a TITLE and the second is a CONVENTIONAL VALUE.

the important thing is, as you can see some of them are repeated (duplicated).

I want an output list of list like this:

---

> p = [['block', 3, 2], ['street', 2, 4], ['lamp', 1, 2], ['industrial',
>   3, 3], ['park', 2, 2], ['park', 3, 1]]

WITH a THIRD value as the FREQUENCY of that inner list, in the outer list x.

so here is my non-pythonic (maybe dull) approach:

---

```
x = [['block', 3], ['street', 2], ['lamp',1], ['street', 2], ['industrial', 3], ['park', 2], ['park', 3], ['industrial', 3], ['block', 3], ['street', 2], ['lamp',1], ['street', 2], ['industrial', 3], ['park', 2]]
p = []

for a in x:
    p.append(a ),  a.append( x.count(a))

print p # checkpoint

i= 0
while i < len(p):
    for j in range(len(p)):
        if i == j:
            print i, ' = ', j
            break
        else:
            if p[i][:2] == p[j][:2]:
                print p[i][:2], '==', p[j][:2]
                p.pop(i)
                i = 0
                j=0
                break
    i = i+1

print p # the list of lists I'm desired
```

---

but for my project, because this function followed by other functions, in comparison to them this one has a high run-time, especially with vast input datasets.

because my lack of the knowledge I couldn't optimize the code I wrote.

so I'm asking is there a faster and more pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use a dictionary. I am *assuming* that order matters, so I will use an `OrderedDict`, but you may consider a `Counter` object, if order does not matter:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> counter = OrderedDict()
>>> for a, b in x:
...     t = (a, b)
...     counter[t] = counter.get(t, 0) + 1
...
>>> final = [[a, b, v] for (a,b),v in counter.items()]
>>> final
[['block', 3, 2], ['street', 2, 4], ['lamp', 1, 2], ['industrial', 3, 3], ['park', 2, 2], ['park', 3, 1]]
```

Just noticed you are on Python 2 (if you can help it, you should really be using Python 3), in which case, since you are on Python 2, you should use `counter.iteritems()` instead of `counter.items()`.

So something like:

```
>>> final = [[a, b, count] for (a, b), count in counter.iteritems()]
>>> final
[['block', 3, 2], ['street', 2, 4], ['lamp', 1, 2], ['industrial', 3, 3], ['park', 2, 2], ['park', 3, 1]]
```

Note, your first for-loop is scales quadratically, and as for that while-loop, I don't feel like thinking about it, I think maybe quadratic as well, but perhaps even worse (because you `.pop(i)`) but the solution I posted above scales linearly. So it should be able to handle much larger datasets effectively.

Comment: thanks for the answer. the code is perfect. but when I look at this, I have no idea how you get to this. how can I improve my thinking-coding ability to code more like your approach? is this something that must achieve by time?

Comment: @AfshinSalehi a lot of practice and seeing similar problems.